# iOS: Should I use Core Data or NSUserDefaults?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsuserdefaults

**Background:**

I have an app that retrieves a list of restaurants from a database, each have an individual array of basic information about them (hours, name, address, etc).  I would like to retrieve that information from the server on the apps first load, but then have it stored within the app itself, with either NSUserDefaults or Core Data, since the information is unlikely to change.  The max number of restaurants I would be storing is about 25, is that a small enough data collection to use NSUserDefaults?

I have looked at similar questions with storing data with over 1,000 records, but I am only storing a small array.

**Question:**

NSUserDefaults is much easier to use than Core Data, so if possible I would like to avoid using Core Data.  In my case, will there be a performance problem if I am storing my list of restaurants in NSUserDefaults instead of Core Data?

Comment: In my view,as long as you clear the nsuserdefaults key when you dont use it, storing an array with 25 values doesnt affect any performance!!!!

Comment: What do you mean by clearing the NSUserDefaults key when I don't use it? I will need to leave that data in that key forever once it is populated

Comment: Data unlikely to change? I wouldn't recommend using NSUserDefaults for this list as that's not what that is for. You're correct that CoreData will be overkill for 25. I recommend storing the NSArray within NSFileManager, or if it's ALWAYS the same... create a plist with the info hard-coded, though this means it can't be changed without an update of course

Comment: @JimTierney I am going to update the array of restaurants about every month, so would you recommend using NSFileManager or NSUserDefaults?

Comment: I'd recommend saving an NSArray to NSFileManager location, where you'd simply overwrite this file with new data each month. NSUserDefaults is meant for storing settings, and user values etc, not for storing data. Using NSFileManager is a basic way, but will work for what you're describing. I also recommend you read up on storing data. CoreData isn't just for storage, that's just a small part of what it does, though worthwhile looking into it. SQLite for databases is also good. NSFileManager is just a quick way to save information locally

Comment: What about neither? How about saving the the information to disk but without the massive overkill of Core Data? This is a poorly phrased question; you've stacked the deck (and wrongly so).

Comment: @matt yes, I think the general consensus is to use NSFileManager instead of either of these two options.  Thanks for the down vote!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on the

- size
- structure of data
- requirements re integrity of the data

Just an Array of 10 or 20 "restaruants" I would certainly store in `NSUserDefaults`. But only when I am sure that this will never become more complex. Because when you later extend your model but started off with NSUserData then you may remain with `NSUserDefaults` just because you avoid migrating it to Core Data during the upgrade of an installed app.

So for more complex structures including references and when you have further plans with your app towards more functionality that may require more entities, then you should go for Core Data from start.

BTW, it is not that complicated as you may think.

However, instead of abusing NSUserDefaults, you could simply write an NSArray to file using `-writeToFile:atomically:` and `-initWithContentsOfFile:` to read them in.

Answer (score 1):

`NSUserDefaults` is not intended for data, it's for storing simple key-value pairs like user settings and flags. Core Data is a bit hard to learn at first, but definitely worth it, even for simple applications.

If it really is a small, simple data set that won't change very often, you can also store some data in a local plist (i.e. save `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` to plist using `writeToFile` method). This isn't very different from using `NSUserDefaults` in terms of performance, although I think it's cleaner and easier to manage.  If it never changes you can also include the plist with your app resources in XCode by creating a plist file and filling it in with your data.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the amount of the data, user default or a specific plist/json file are all good. CoreData is definitely overkilling.